# Wrong and weird lightning on a very simple mesh

Tags: opengl, shader, normals

I've been trying to correctly generate 3D figures like planes, spheres and cubes. But I'm trying to apply illumination to them so I also generate normals.

Here's my output from a simple plane, I'm only using triangles and I'm using a positional light:

```
Vertice 0: 3.000000 3.000000 0.000000
Vertice 1: 3.000000 -3.000000 0.000000
Vertice 2: -3.000000 -3.000000 0.000000
Vertice 3: -3.000000 3.000000 0.000000
Normal: 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
Normal: -0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Sometimes it lights it right and sometimes it shows in that way, with the 2 OBVIOUS triangles.

What do you think might be the reason for this?

---

Here's the vertex shader:

```
attribute highp vec4 vertices;
attribute highp vec3 normals;
uniform mediump mat4 projectMatrix;
uniform mediump mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mediump mat4 modelMatrix;
out highp vec3 normal;
out highp vec4 pos_ws;
out lowp vec4 lightp_cs;

void main (void)
{
    vec4 PPos= vec4(3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0);

gl_Position= projectMatrix*viewMatrix*modelMatrix*vertices;
normal= normals;
    pos_ws= viewMatrix*modelMatrix * vec4(vertices);
    lightp_cs= viewMatrix* PPos;
}
```

And this is the fragment shader:

```
in highp vec3 normal;
in highp vec4 pos_ws;
in lowp vec4 lightp_cs;

void main(void)
{
vec4 ambient= vec4 (0.276, 0.342, 0.417, 1.0);

vec4 DiffuseColor= vec4 (0.40234375, 0.40234375, 0.40234375, 1.0);

    vec4 PColor= vec4(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);
    //vec4 PPos= vec4(3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0);
vec3 PAtt= vec3(0.6, 0.050, 0.005);

// Para la luz puntual
    //vec4 vToLight= pos_ws - PPos;
    vec4 vToLight= pos_ws - lightp_cs;
vToLight= normalize(vToLight);
float distToLight= length(vToLight);
vec4 Vnormal= vec4(normal, 1.0);

    float cosNPL= clamp(dot(Vnormal, -vToLight), 0, 1);
float PLAtt= (PAtt.x + PAtt.y * distToLight + PAtt.z * distToLight * distToLight);

gl_FragColor= ambient + (DiffuseColor * (cosNPL * PColor)/PLAtt); // Luz Puntual
}
```

Comment: How are you rendering the triangles? `v0 v1 v2` and `v2 v0 v3`? or `v0 v1 v2` `v1 v2 v3`?

Comment: Can you at least give the relevant parts of your code or give a more rigorous description on how you generated this image?

Comment: I render them in the next order:

V0, V2 and V1
and then
V3, V2 and V0

So it would be CCW.

I'll also edit the question with the vertex and fragment shaders...

Comment: Looks like you supply wrong or garbaged normals to the render, e.g. by using wrong offsets in VAO/VBO.

Comment: I will check that as soon as possible and I'll post the results! Thanks!

Comment: Why are there only two normals? Each vertex has a normal. BTW, Vertices **are not** just positions. A vertex is the vector formed from [position, normal, color, texture coordinates, etc.]. So you need to supply the full set for each vertex.

Comment: 1.You forget to transform normals from model space to world space !!! (at least i do not see it) 2.I do not see the obvious two side normal (if your triangles have opposite winding then the light is inverted to each other ... should fabs the dot-product of normal and light direction...

Comment: ps. do not forget that the transform of normals is without offset !!! (origin of all matrices involved is (0,0,0)) so your transformed value is still vector and not position

Comment: you did not check your float values on zero in fragment shader, it's  may be part of issue. try to apply solid color, or with less math in fragment shader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved now.

datenwolf was right. I was only considering face's normals, since I started to calculate and give to opengl the vertices' normals, the plane is being rendered correctly.

[image]

I'll also take into account Spektre's answer, I guess you're talking about the normal matrix. I will do that too.

Since I'm just generating a plane, the real challenge will come when I start to generate a sphere. I also don't know if the order you pass the normals makes any difference (face normal, vertex normal, f, v, f, f, v, etc), I think it doesn't.

Anyway, thanks to everyone! :)